# How to parse JSON in a non 200 status code in JS's Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, http-headers

My fetch request is as follows -

```
fetch(base_url + "/user/details", options)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error(response.json().message);
        }
      })
      .then(responseJson => processResponse(responseJson))
      .catch(error => handleError(error));
```

When the response is not `ok` (400 in this case) the JSON looks like this -

```
{"timestamp":"2020-08-27T14:44:21.077176","message":"Failed for some reason."}
```

However, when I try to access the above response (like this - `response.json().message`), I get a blank.

How do I access the JSON in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a **promise**

It won't have a `message` property, only its resolved value does.

---

```
const response = await fetch(base_url + "/user/details", options);
const data = await response.json();
if (response.ok) {
    return processResponse(data);
}
handleError(new Error(data.message));
```

Comment: That explains the missing message value. Then, how do I access it?

Comment: Same way you deal with any promise, return `response.json()` and then read it in the next `then`. (I'd tend to rewrite things to use `async`/`await` as I find it makes it easier to follow).

Comment: Could you please write some code to explain this? I can't understand how to add `then` in `catch`?